# Create set-up file with data base

Tags: c#, mysql, inno-setup

I've created set up file using IS in C# with the data base. But when I install it I had following error.

Failed to update , because data base is read-only.

How can I solve this issue??

Comment: Where did you put the database? if it is in the prorams folder - RTFM. Like where application data should go and that the program folder is supposed to be read only.

Comment: Yeah my DB is in this path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuwan C", I don't know about the programs folder is read only. what should I do?

Comment: Not store it in the program folder? Read the documentation before making a setup - tons of programs around that are made by ignorants that do not know how to make a setup. Do not join them. There is a special location for application data - well, two, one for user specific data, one for shared user data.

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to fully understand the issue with the very few information you have provided, what I think I understand is that the initial setup goes well and when you run [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) again to update your application the local data base file is in use and does not let you overwrite it... well, good luck it is because if not what would happen to user data entered with your app since the first install of the application?

in general for data based applications following updates of the application binaries should not simply overwrite the whole database files with an empty one included in the setup, you should find a way to update database schema or add / update reference data by including some update scripts execution within your installer, when you detect that you are doing an update rather than a first install.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Setup runs smoothly and install all the components. But the problem is db cannot update. I followed way to change the read only property but I can't found a way. I'm sure I didn't enter null values for the DB. Update means that not an update query. I've got that error when I inputting the data